# How to show the variance of the inter-arrival time of a Cox process driven by a Poisson process of constant intensity $\lambda$ is $3\lambda$

Tags: variance, expected-value, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

Ideas on how to show that the variance of a doubly-stochastic Poisson process(aka a [Cox process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process)) driven by a homogeneous(stationary) Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$ is $3\lambda$ ?

I've come to this conjecture from simulation with the following Java code

```
package stochastic.processes;

import java.util.function.DoubleSupplier;

import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ExponentialDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomGenerator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.Well19937c;

public class CoxProcess implements DoubleSupplier {


    private final ExponentialDistribution intensityDistribution;

    RandomGenerator generator;

    public CoxProcess( double intensity )
    {
        this( new Well19937c(), intensity );
    }

    public CoxProcess( RandomGenerator generator, double intensity )
    {
        this.generator = generator;
        intensityDistribution = new ExponentialDistribution( 1.0 / intensity);
    }

    @Override
    public double getAsDouble()
    {
        ExponentialDistribution dist = new ExponentialDistribution(generator, intensityDistribution.sample());
        return dist.sample();
    }
}
```

[image]